# Is there a way to restore a database in MSSQL using .mdf files?

Tags: sql-server, linux, docker

I upgraded my ubuntu server from 20.04 to 22.04 and after the upgrade MSSQL stopped working cause Microsoft doesn't support this version of Ubuntu yet. I lost the backup file of the database(Cause I had a copy in another computer which I don't have currently access to), but I still have the mdfs, logs, .conf and secrets files and folders inside mssql data. I reinstalled MSSQL on a docker container and I thought to take these mdf and ldf files(inside data folder) and replace them on docker. I changed the ownership of files, but still getting error access denied. How I can get this working?
The error I get:

```
2022-08-29 12:23:36.25 spid20s     Starting up database 'master'.
2022-08-29 12:23:36.27 spid20s     Error: 17204, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2022-08-29 12:23:36.27 spid20s     FCB::Open failed: Could not open file /var/opt/mssql/data/master.mdf for file number 1.  OS error: 5(Access is denied.).
2022-08-29 12:23:36.28 spid20s     Error: 5120, Severity: 16, State: 101.
2022-08-29 12:23:36.28 spid20s     Unable to open the physical file "/var/opt/mssql/data/master.mdf". Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)".
2022-08-29 12:23:36.31 spid20s     Error: 17204, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2022-08-29 12:23:36.31 spid20s     FCB::Open failed: Could not open file /var/opt/mssql/data/mastlog.ldf for file number 2.  OS error: 5(Access is denied.).
2022-08-29 12:23:36.32 spid20s     Error: 5120, Severity: 16, State: 101.
2022-08-29 12:23:36.32 spid20s     Unable to open the physical file "/var/opt/mssql/data/mastlog.ldf". Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)".
```

Comment: It seems like the files are there but the OS is denying access. Have you tried setting open permissions on those files (i.e. chmod 777) just to see if that works? My concern is that continuing to move files around is not addressing the underlying issue and could potentially not be fruitful.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I didn't check for hidden folders. So, I just removed everything inside the /var/opt/mssql/ folder that includes:

- *.system/* - which I didn't see before
- *data/*
- *secrets/*
- *log/*
- *mssql.conf*

And I replaced them with the corresponding files and folders, by **switching** also the ownership of every file and folder to the right user (In my case of docker it was mssql).